# VSTO Addin, AppointmentItem How to Save without Sending an update to recipients

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a case where I want to save some UserProperties to the AppointmentItem but (if there are any recipients) it pops up an outlook dialog to Send it first.
How can I prevent this dialog. Even I do have recipients I should be able to save the AppointmentItem but apparently outlook doesn't saving without sending an update.
On the other hand calling Send on an AppointmentItem closes the explorer window and I couldn't find how to prevent that too.

`appointmentItem.UserProperties.Add("LastUpdated", OlUserPropertyType.olText, true);
appointmentItem.UserProperties["LastUpdated"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
appointmentItem.Save(); // This line shows the prompt`

Comment: What is your code that causes that prompt to show up?

Comment: `if (this.Item.UserProperties["LastUpdated"] == null)
                this.Item.UserProperties.Add("LastUpdated", OlUserPropertyType.olText, true);
            this.Item.UserProperties["LastUpdated"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString

this.Item.Save();
`

Comment: So which call exactly causes the prompt? UserProperties.Add? Item.Save?

Comment: Every time `Item.Save();` is called the prompt is shown.

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: So if you don't set the user properties, you don't get the prompt?

Comment: If I make any changes to the appointmentItem and call appointmentItem.Save(), it gives the prompt to Send an update to recipients.

Comment: I can only suggest bypassing OOM and using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (any language, use RDO family of objects) .

Comment: 1- Can Redemption also provide me a surefire solution to listen ( and may interrupt/cancel) Outlook Calendar events?
2- Can I also work that out in VC++ in a library and use it later in my C# solution?

Comment: Redemption can be used alongside OOM - you can leave your code intact and use Redemption to only open, modify, and save the appointment. Create an instance of the RDOSession object, set ist MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT from OOM (this way they will share the same session), then open the appointment using RDOSession.GetMessageFromID or RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject and cast the returned object to RDOAppointmentItem.